# Excel find if user paid monthly invoice

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two worksheets

Worksheet1 looks like:

```
Customer  | June | July | August
John      |      |      |     
Jane      |      |      |     
Bob       |      |      |     
Ann       |      |      |
```

Worksheet2 looks like:

```
Customer  | Paid Amount | Month
John      | $50         | June    
Jane      | $20         | June    
Bob       | $100        | June    
Ann       | $10         | June  

John      | $30         | July    
Jane      | $40         | July      
Ann       | $5          | July  

Bob       | $10         | August
John      | $10         | August
Jane      | $20         | August
```

In Worksheet1 I need a formula that simply returns a string, like "Paid" or "Not Paid", by taking the Customer name from Worksheet1, doing a lookup on Worksheet2 for that customer name, and checking if there is a payment record for that month. Based on the example data above, the result in Worksheet1 should look like:

```
Customer  | June | July     | August
John      | Paid | Paid     | Paid    
Jane      | Paid | Paid     | Paid    
Bob       | Paid | Not Paid | Paid   
Ann       | Paid | Paid     | Not Paid
```

I tried the following:

```
IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([@Customer],table_from_Worksheet2,2,FALSE)),"No","Yes")
```

Problem is that's checking the entire Worksheet2 and not filtering by the month in question. I need to somehow tweak the VLOOKUP (or use another method such as INDEX and MATCH but I don't know how to use them) to find if customer made a payment for that specific month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the formula in B2 on worksheet1 (Where John and June meet) and copy across and down. Be sure to enter the formula with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Worksheet2!$B$2:$B$12,MATCH($A2,IF(B$1=Worksheet2!$C$2:$C$12,Worksheet2!$A$2:$A$12),0)),"Paid","Not Paid"),"Not Paid")
```

For a table you can use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Table_from_Worksheet2[Paid Amount],MATCH([@Customer],IF(B$1=Table_from_Worksheet2[Month],Table_from_Worksheet2[Customer]),0)),"Paid","Not Paid"),"Not Paid")
```

You will also need to enter with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**
Please note, you are going to need to adjust the ranges as neccessary.

Comment: Thanks rwilson. I'm having trouble adjusting the ranges. All the data in Worksheet2 is in a table called "table_from_Worksheet2". Is there a way to replace the ranges with the table name? That way as I add data to the table, I won't have to change the ranges in my formula.

Comment: I just added a table formula to my answer.

Comment: Accepted. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a pivot table with "month" in the column labels box, "Name" in the row labels box, and "count of paid amount" in the values box.

Select your whole table on sheet 2.

Select *Insert-->PivotTable*  (Far left of the ribbon)

Drag and drop the categories as I described above.

This will give you a 1 in every month/name combination where a customer has paid, and a blank otherwise.  Now select the interior of your Pivot Table, Right Click and "Change Format"  Select Custom Format, and scroll down to the Type called `"TRUE";"TRUE";"FALSE"` and apply.

Right Click on the "Grand Total" and "Remove Grand Total" if you so desire.

Pivot tables are scary at first, but very powerful and worth learning.

(I added another person before I made the table below)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Adam. Really cool method, I'll have to learn more about pivot tables. Unfortunately I can't accept your answer only because when I created the pivot table it re-arranged my Months in a very strange way. The original table went from June 2014 to July 2015 top to bottom and when I created the pivot table it went all wonky http://ctrlv.in/617382. Regardless I upvoted your answer because you have shown me the value in pivot tables :)

Comment: Your dates are currently text, so instead of reading the dates oldest to newest the pivot table is reading them alphabetically. April, August, December,etc.

Comment: Rwilson is correct about the dates being text.  I would fix that regardless of whether or not the pivot table is used.  As a side note, it _is_ possible to re-arrange pivot table order, (select a head, then hover till you get a hand icon, and drag them to where you want them)  It would be a pain, though, with as many months as you have there.